# How to get rpush to recognize a new certificate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl-certificate, apple-push-notifications

This concerns the rpush gem, a push notification service that I am using for Apple push notifications. I'm using the Rpush::Apns2 mode.

I'm having a mysterious problem getting rpush to see a new certificate that I've created. I'm using it in a ruby on rails environment and running it as a daemon. I have the rpush.rb initializer set up to trigger an exception when the certificate will expire within the month. It recently started getting triggered.

```
on.ssl_certificate_will_expire do |app, expiration_time|
  raise "Apple Push notification certificate for #{app.name} will expire at #{expiration_time}."
end
```

The exception that is raised is "[2021-11-28 00:00:24] [ERROR] RuntimeError, Apple Push notification certificate for recode will expire at 2021-12-04 19:31:50 UTC." The main text of the exception was defined by me in the rpush.rb initializer.

So I have a new certificate and put it in config/private. It expires about a year from now.

```
$ openssl x509 -in apple_push_notification.pem -noout -text
Certificate:
  Data:
    .
    .
    .
    Validity
        Not Before: Nov  4 21:08:56 2021 GMT
        Not After : Dec  4 21:08:55 2022 GMT
```

In the console, I read the new certificate into the app record:

```
app = Rpush::Client::ActiveRecord::Apns2::App.find_by(name: APP_NAME)
app.certificate = File.read(CERTIFICATE_PATH)
app.save!
```

Upon examination, the certificate in the record matches the file.

I tried stopping and starting the service:

```
$ systemctl --user stop rpush

$ systemctl --user status rpush
Nov 22 09:23:48 aa systemd[888]: Stopping rpush...
Nov 22 09:23:48 aa rpush[1111]: * Booting Rails 'production' environment... ✔
Nov 22 09:23:48 aa rpush[1111]: [2B blob data]
Nov 22 09:23:48 aa systemd[888]: rpush.service: Succeeded.

Nov 22 09:23:48 aa systemd[888]: Stopped rpush.

$ systemctl --user start rpush
```

But still, the exception gets triggered. I also tried killing it on the command line directly, still, the exception gets triggered. Somehow, the old certificate is somewhere that rpush can see.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Please include the exception that is referenced in the question.

Comment: The exception that is raised is (for example) "[2021-11-28 00:00:24] [ERROR] RuntimeError, Apple Push notification certificate for recode will expire at 2021-12-04 19:31:50 UTC."  The "Apple Push notification certificate for recode will expire at 2021-12-04 19:31:50 UTC." was defined by me in the rpush.rb initializer

Comment: Thanks! It's best to add that info to the question, to make it more visible, else some people might miss it. You can edit your question to add it there.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out -- and just in time as we only had 3 days left! It turns out there were 2 app records in the database with the same name. One was of type "Rpush::Client::ActiveRecord::Apns2::App" the other of type "Rpush::Client::ActiveRecord::App" I believe. We had switched from the legacy protocol to Apns2 last year and so the Apns2 app is the one currently being used, however it looks like I added the certificate to the old one.

The solution is to delete the app record corresponding to the old protocol and perform the above procedure of adding the certificate to the correct app record. Then, restart the rpush service.